# Big query error - “Unexpected. Please try again” trying to export

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to export data from my table, but I always get unexpected error :(

```
Extract1:18pm
enduring-lane-563:datosLilin.tareasCuentasAmbosIdtogs://datoslilin/test.csv
Errors:
Unexpected. Please try again.
Job ID: enduring-lane-563:job_Q3y3u3qBYYD95qTz2wYL1edw1XE
Start Time: 1:18pm, 9 Oct 2014
End Time: 1:18pm, 9 Oct 2014
Source Table: enduring-lane-563:datosLilin.tareasCuentasAmbosId
Destination URI: gs://datoslilin/test.csv



Extract1:11pm
enduring-lane-563:1234test.copiatogs://datoslilin/text.csv
Errors:
Unexpected. Please try again.
Job ID: enduring-lane-563:job_y67jw9l63z5hOyznFcDBIG_G48Y
Start Time: 1:11pm, 9 Oct 2014
End Time: 1:11pm, 9 Oct 2014
Source Table: enduring-lane-563:1234test.copia
Destination URI: gs://datoslilin/text.csv
```